# Remote VNC session as local x-session

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, hotkeys

So i seek for a way to make VNC as more comfortable as possible.
I have Linux mint + kde on both home at work. When i use vncviewer and try to use most of hotkeys like ALT+TAB and others, of course they all captured by local system. It's not comfortable to press F8 all the time, as developer i use hotkeys very regularly.

Question: is there a way to open remote vnc picture as local xsession? or somehow else completely capture all local hotkeys and send to remote vnc server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to run the vncviewer in fullscreen (--fullscreen or fullScreen property), without a window manager at all (exec vnciewer in .xinitrc instead of exec $WINDOWMANAGER), and with grabbed keyboard (grabKeyboard property in .Xresources). That gets as close to making a remote desktop the same as a local one as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! is there a way i could do that on running system? say, press CTRL+ALT+F1, do something, get vnc session?

Comment: Basically press C-A-F1 to go to the console, then use startx/xinit to launch another X instance, modify your .xinitrc to select whether to start your preferred desktop environment or vnc based on the $DISPLAY variable, also properly configure .Xresources. Then another X instance starts and you should be able to switch using eg. C-A-F7 and C-A-F8 between them.